# Matrix data not showing in CP, but displays in templates

Tags: matrix, solspace, solspace-importer

EE 2.7.3
Matrix 2.5.10
MAMP, PHP 5.5.3

This is a weird one, working on a fresh site build, data from a Matrix field is showing in my template, but when I go to edit in the CP no rows display in the CP. If I save the entry then the data is gone and nothing displays in the template. I'm not sure when the field stopped displaying data in the CP, but it WAS showing in the CP at one point.

I'm also working with Solspace Importer for this particular channel, and the last import I did was for non Matrix fields in the same channel, not sure if this could have anything to do with the Matrix data not showing in the CP… I import the Matrix data via the XML importer, wondering if that needs to be done last? That still wouldn't explain why Matrix data is not showing in the CP though.

Comment: What version of Importer are you using? Also, try importing your data first, _then_ Matrix data last. The way the EE Channel Entries API and Matrix support for the API works, previous Matrix data might be removed when applying an import for non-Matrix fields last on a pre-existing entry.

Comment: I'm using 2.2.3. OK that's a good suggestion and will work for now. Just an update - I noticed the same thing happened to a playa field as well… I will treat that the same way and run the imports for matrix and playa after general fields.